# Custom Array Item Name for DTO

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, xml-serialization, datacontractserializer

One of my clients has XML data he wants to send to a service we are creating. A sample message might look like:

```
<SomeRootElement>
  <Dates>
    <Date>2012-05-20T00:00:00</Date>
    <Date>2012-05-21T00:00:00</Date>
  </Dates>
</SomeRootElement>
```

I have a corresponding type defined as a `DataContract` on my WCF service application:

```
[DataContract]
public class SomeRootElement {
    [DataMember]
    public ICollection<DateTime> Dates { get; set; }
}
```

The trouble is that based on this definition, WCF wants the `Dates` collection to look like:

```
<Dates>
  <dateTime>2012-05-20T00:00:00</dateTime>
  <dateTime>2012-05-21T00:00:00</dateTime>
</Dates>
```

Is there any way to influence the array item's serialized element name?  This used to be easy using XML serialization attributes, but the `DataContractSerializer` ignores those.

Comment: You can add [XmlSerializerFormat] attribute to the class so it will make use of the Xml serialization attributes

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick:

```
[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(DateList))]
public class SomeRootElement {
    [DataMember]
    public ICollection<DateTime> Dates { get; set; }
}

[CollectionDataContract(ItemName="date")]
public class DateList : Collection<DateTime>  {}
```

You are overriding the type it can use for deserializing the ICollection for a customized one.

Comment: It seems like this should work, but it isn't.  The WSDL contains a line for `<xs:element xmlns:q1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays" minOccurs="0" name="Dates" nillable="true" type="q1:ArrayOfdateTime"/>`. It doesn't have any mention of the array item name being `date` instead.

Comment: It seems you are doing something like `element.Dates = new Date[...]`. Try `element.Dates = new DateList();` instead